# area of a triangle from coordinates and altitude

Tags: linear-algebra

I am using the math that I have learned thus far and I would appreciate if somebody could check my logic without offering alternative solutions.

I am given the coordinates for A, B and C as (2, 3), (4, 9) and (10, -3) respectively and I am first of all asked to find the equation of AH, the altitude of triangle ABC.

I work out the gradient of BC which is ${{-3 -9} \over {10 -4}} = {{-12 \over 2} = -2}$ so the gradient of AH is ${1\over 2}$.

The equation of the line for AH is ${y -3 = {1\over 2}(x - 2)}$ or when I get it into the form ${Ax + By + c}$ it is:

${x -2y + 4 = 0}$

I am then asked to find the area of the triangle.

By my reckoning I need to find the length of sides AH multiply HC divided by 2.

In order to find the length of AH I need to the point that AH intersects with BC so I need to find the equation of the line BC.

BC has a gradient of -2 so the equation of the line is ${y - 9 = -2x + 8}$

In ${Ax + Bx + C}$ form it is ${2x + y - 17 =0}$

I multiply the equation of AH by -2 and add it to the equation of the line for BC and get

${-2x + 4y -8 = 0}$

${ 2x  + y - 17 = 0}$

---

${      5y -25  = 0}$

${y = 5}$

If I plug that into the equation ${x - 2y + 4 = 0}$

I get ${x -10 + 4 = 0 => x = 6}$ so the coordinates of AH are (6, 5).

I then find the length of AH from the point (6, 5) and (2, 3) which is:

${\sqrt{(6 -2)^2 + (5 - 3)^2}}$ = ${\sqrt {16 + 4}}$ = ${\sqrt 20}$

The length of HC is:

${\sqrt {(10 - 6)^2 + (-3 - 5)^2 }}$ = ${\sqrt {16 + 64}}$ = ${\sqrt 80}$

So my answer would be along the lines of ${{{\sqrt 20} x  {\sqrt 80}} \over 2}$

I think I have taken a wrong turn because the answer in the textbook to what is the area of the triangle ABC is 30 units so I'm not sure where I have gone wrong.

Comment: The area is not given by $\frac{AH\cdot HC}{2}$, it is $\frac{AH\cdot\color{red}{BC}}{2}$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you took a slightly inefficient way. $H\in BC$ has to fulfill:

$$ H = (1-\lambda)(4,9)+\lambda (10,-3),\qquad AH\perp BC $$
hence by imposing $\langle A-H,B-C\rangle = 0$ we get:
$$ -6(2+6\lambda)+12(6-12\lambda)=0$$
hence $\lambda=\frac{1}{3}$ and $H=(6,5)$. After that:
$$ \Delta = \frac{1}{2}\|A-H\|\cdot\|B-C\| = \frac{1}{2}\sqrt{20}\sqrt{180}=\color{red}{30}.$$

Comment: What is this algorithm?

Comment: @dagda1: which step is not clear?

Comment: I am trying to solve the problem with the knowledge I have learned thus far.  I'd really appreciate it if somebody would check my logic.

Comment: @dagda1: checked. Please see the comment just below your question.

Comment: Yes, thank you.

Comment: Do you have a link or is there a name for this way of finding the area of a triangle.  It is much more concise than mine.

Comment: @dagda1: "my way" is just the usual way - half the product between the length of a side and the length of the corresponding height.

Comment: I meant for your first solution to the problem and not the area of a triangle.

Comment: I do not understand what the question is. Are you referring to the dot product between $A-H$ and $B-C$ being zero for expressing $AH\perp BC$?

Answer (score 0):

Hint:

$A=(2,3)$, so the line $AH$ is $y-3=\frac{1}{2}(x-2)$.

And to find the length of $AH$ you can use the [formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distance_from_a_point_to_a_line#Line_defined_by_an_equation) for a distance from the point $A$ and the line: $ y-9=-2(x-4)$ that passes through $B$ and $C$.